# finding PCIe lanes in linux

Tags: linux, pci, pci-express

I have a PCIe (ver 2) linux system. I want to find out how many PCIe lanes were negotiated and are being used between my device and the host controller . (I do not know how many lanes my device supports or how many lanes the slot has)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`lspci -vv` should give you this information, look for the "Width" part in the `LnkCap` section.

Comment: Note that "LnkCap" is the capability of the slot, and "LnkSta" is the actual status of the card. I had to run this as root to get the link info.